# Automatically delete / unlist YouTube video after Live Stream ends

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

As far as I remember, the enableDvr flag used to work like this. If it was not set, the video would not get archived. This is how we used it in our implementation. However, recently we got feedback that the videos with the flag disabled stay in YouTube after the live stream ends.

Has there been a change in the API and how this flag is used?

Also, the documentation states:

```
Important: You must set the value to true and also set the enableArchive property's value to true if you want to make playback available immediately after the broadcast ends.
```

On the other hand, the API changelog states that the enableArchive flag was removed back in 2013... Why is it still in the documentation then?

In addition, when setting up an event in YouTube Creators Studio there is an option to automatically unlist the video after the live stream ends. I can't find this option in the LiveBroadcast object. Is it available via the API or would I need to unlist or delete the video manually when the broadcast ends?

Answer (score 1):

They have a defect in their documentation. In the March 27, 2013 revision history, they renamed this property to `recordFromStart`.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#recordFromStart